# Taking a random sample of rows from a data frame in R. How do I use the rows that were not sampled?

Tags: r, dataframe, random

Taking a random sample without replacement from a data frame. I assigned that sample to a new data frame. I want to use the rows that are left over from that sample.

To create the sample, I used:

```
telemarketing_sample <- telemarketing[sample(1:nrow(telemarketing), 30000, replace=FALSE),]
```

Comment: If you know the row indices you took, simply subset the original data frame based on the indices you did not take.

Comment: I have 40,000+ rows. I'm not sure which ones are taken and which ones are not. I thought there'd maybe be a function that can compare two data frames and see which rows are taken, which ones are not, and then take the rows that are not.

Comment: Perhaps you can record the number of rows first, then take random samples from the sequence starting 1 to the number of rows. By doing this you will know the row indices.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Would you please rephrase that? (thanks for helping by the way)

Comment: Add the code expression you used to sample the rows to your question.

Comment: All I have really is a dataframe called telemarketing and 

telemarketing_sample <- telemarketing[sample(1:nrow(telemarketing), 30000,
   replace=FALSE),]

Comment: That's why it is hard for you to get the opposite. Save the sample so you can use it later.

Comment: See the answer below. Next time add an example of your data to get an answer.

Comment: Saving that sample isn't an issue. I want to save the sample that I didn't take. Idk how to do that.

Comment: Seems clear, I'll try it. Thanks for all of your help!!!!

Comment: If it works come back and mark the answer as complete

Comment: I will do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually it is helpful to provide some code that you have already tried to give folks something to start with. In the meantime, something like this should work:

```
#generate some toy data
x <- data.frame(id = 1:100, y = rep(c(0,1),50))

#get a sample of 10
samp <- sample(nrow(x),10)

#data in the sample
in <- x[samp,]

#data not in the sample
out <- x[-samp,]
```

Comment: This answer is perfect. If you are using the package `dplyr`, this may also work: `out <- dplyr::setdiff(x, in)`
`

Comment: (@mattysatty don't apologize, just offering feedback for next time & for other users who may see the q&a :) happy it helped!)